# Using Invoke-Webrequest in powershell with cookies

Tags: powershell

I'd like to know how I can use Invoke-WebRequest and enable registeration of cookies.
Currently there's a site that uses get/set and cookies and it's sort of built of thousands of pages. Each page consists the ID of the next page and I tried doing a loop that runs through and refers me to the last page, but because the webrequest doesnt keep the cookies, it keeps thinking im still on page 1.

How can I enable the storage of cookies for the webrequest so it wont think im still there?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the session-related switches of `Invoke-WebRequest`. Your first request should use the `-SessionVariable` switch to choose the variable in which the cookies will be stashed:

```
iwr http://example.com/Page1 -SessionVariable session
```

Note the lack of `$` on `session` - that command *creates* a variable with the given name. After that command, you have a `$session` variable, which you can then pass as the `-WebSession` in all subsequent requests:

```
iwr http://example.com/Page2 -WebSession $session
```

Example 2 in [the Microsoft documentation on `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1#examples) shows how to sign in to Facebook using this technique.